# Changing the chart color dynamically based on value in gs

Tags: stacked-bar-chart

I'd like to change the color of the stacked bar chart based on the changing values in google sheets. Currently the color is set and what I'm trying to accomplish is to set conditional formatting for chart color. In other words, if the change in value is positive, the stacked bar color would turn green. Conversely, if the change in value is negative the bar color would show as red. Any input is appreciated.

[google sheets bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAuAR.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I was able to do this with g-script but initially I was looking for possible options to tweak within charts inside google sheets.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this with g-script but initially I was looking for possible options to tweak within charts inside google sheets.